# tail -f on a dynamically generated list of files

Tags: linux, bash

With bash I'm wondering how to `tail -f` all the files matching a certain pattern (typically `*.log`) even when new files matching this pattern appear?
Obviously

```
tail -f *.log
```

or

```
find . -name "*.log" | xargs -r tail -f
```

is not working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `even when new files matching this pattern appear?` inotifywait on the directory to wait for new files, for each new file run `tail -f` in the background

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because your question is better suited to [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

Had you tried multitail ?
https://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/

At least in ubuntu you can apt-get it .

Comment: If the question was a request for a software recommendation, that would make it off-topic here.

Comment: (KamilCuk's suggested approach to solving the problem is a good one, and if the OP were trying to write a program for the purpose, questions about specific issues encountered when developing that program would definitely be on-topic).